# c++ error declaring vector in header file

Tags: c++, valarray

can't find an answer to this anywhere. haven't used c++ for long. in this file, 512, 256, 4736, and 448 all red-underlined as error 'expecting type specifier'

```
// AttackSqrs.h
#include <valarray> 
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map> 
#include <string> 
#include <iostream>

class AttackSqrs
{
public:
    AttackSqrs();
    ~AttackSqrs();

private:
    void init();
    std::valarray<int> board(512);
    std::valarray<int> vrChessPieces(256);
    std::valarray<int> vrAttackSqrs(4736);
    std::valarray<int> vrNumAttackSqrsEachSqr(448);
};
```

but when i create this header file:

```
// diag.h
#include <valarray> 
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map> 
#include <string> 
#include <iostream>


    void init();
    std::valarray<int> board(512);
    std::valarray<int> vrChessPieces(256);
    std::valarray<int> vrAttackSqrs(4736);
    std::valarray<int> vrNumAttackSqrsEachSqr(448);
```

the errors go away. thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: You can't use parentheses for non-static data member initializers.

Comment: If you haven't any memory of C++, why not get a book and learn it systematically? Whar you wrote isn't valid syntax.

Answer (score 1):

You don't initialize members that way.  Use the initialization list of the `AttackSqrs` constructor:

```
class AttackSqrs
{
    public:
    AttackSqrs();
    ~AttackSqrs();

private:
    void init();
    std::valarray<int> board;
    std::valarray<int> vrChessPieces;
    std::valarray<int> vrAttackSqrs;
    std::valarray<int> vrNumAttackSqrsEachSqr;
};

// Then in a CPP file
AttackSqrs::AttackSqrs() :  board(512), vrChessPieces(256), vrAttackSqrs(4736), 
                 vrNumAttackSqrsEachSqr(448) {}
```

Answer (score 1):

On the header file, you only declare the variable and their types. Any kind of object construction is implemented in the cpp file.

**AttackSqrs.h**

```
class AttackSqrs
{
public:
    AttackSqrs();
    ~AttackSqrs();

private:
    void init();
    std::valarray<int> board;
    std::valarray<int> vrChessPieces;
    std::valarray<int> vrAttackSqrs;
    std::valarray<int> vrNumAttackSqrsEachSqr;
};
```

**AttackSqrs.cpp**

```
AttackSqrs::AttackSqrs() : 
        board(512), 
        vrChessPieces(256), 
        vrAttackSqrs(4736), 
        vrNumAttackSqrsEachSqr(448){

}
```

Comment: C++11 allows for initializing members in the class definition.

Comment: That's new to me. You refer to using more template arguments, like Neil Kirk answered?

Comment: I believe there is new C++11 syntax to call constructor of members in class definition, but I'm not familiar with it.

Comment: @BrunoWerminghoff, It's as simple as `int m_i = 5;` to initialize `m_i` to 5 by default. You can use copy-initialization or list-initialization, but not direct-initialization.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is about vectors but you use valarray, which I haven't used before. I will answer for vectors.

You need to set the size of the vectors in the constructor.

header file

```
class AttackSqrs
{
public:
    AttackSqrs();
    ~AttackSqrs();

private:
     std::vector<int> board(512);
};
```

cpp file

```
AttackSqrs::AttackSqrs()
: board(512)
{
}
```

Alternatively, as the sizes are constant, you can use arrays.

```
class AttackSqrs
{
public:
    AttackSqrs();
    ~AttackSqrs();

private:
    std::array<int, 512> board; // c++11
    int board[512]; // pre-c++11
};
```